# Incrementing value read from spreadsheet exploding. 1 + 1 = 200 000 000 000

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I read a value (in this case `7`) from a Google Spreadsheet with a script, increase that value using `source++` and write the increment back to the spreadsheet.

I expect a series of `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`.

Instead, I get `7`, `800 000 000 000`, `900 000 000 000`, `100 000 000 000`.

(Please note the 900 billion to 100 billion “increase.”)

`source = (source+1)` behaves identical.

What's going on here?

MWE:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I98atMSUqwsEpt_EMjbHm1sdWQg5Bgn8ABsEz-2E2wE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known bug in new Sheets](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3724) whereby the spreadsheet regional settings generate an incorrect output. From the [entry on this duplicate issue ticket](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3693#c1):

> If regional settings are set to US then setValue/setValues works
>   properly. If regional settings are German, Polish, Russia and possibly
>   others then there are different results! 
>   Polish - 1.00000000000000
>   German - 100.000.000.000

[For Google Apps Script questions you may get a better response in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)]

Comment: Looks like this bug is fixed now https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3724#c15

Answer (score 1):

I've copied your sheet and ran the code; I get the same results.

However, when I create a new Spreadsheet and run the code on the new sheet, the problem disappears.